# Is it possible to pass a parameter to a MS query SELECT statement as a column?

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2010, parameterized

I'd like to put a SQL query in an `Excel 2010` spreadsheet where one of the columns in the SELECT will be a parameter.

I've played around with it for a bit with different table aliases and changing the command text from within the connection properties box with no success.  It just gives me various errors with each attempt.  I tried googling but found nothing on the subject.  I suspect that it is simply impossible to do this using a standard database query as MS query is quite limiting.  Can someone verify that it is indeed impossible to have a SQL query in Excel with a column name in the `SELECT` as a parameter?  If it is not impossible could you share how to get it to work?

It'd be something like...

```
SELECT tble.Date, tble.Hour, tble.[parameter]
FROM my_table tble
```

I'd want some parameterized wheres once I got the above to work.

Comment: `1.`Can you show us your select query? `2.`Are you looking for a parameterized query..? `3.` What does this mean ***impossible to have a SQL query in Excel with a column name in the SELECT as a parameter***? Is the column name coming from `database` or `Excel Sheet`?

Comment: I added more specifics to my question. The column name would come from Excel Sheet.  I meant in the SELECT before the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the query string that you are looking for? Assuming you are getting data from cells where cell range act as the table in this case:-

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS
FROM   [Sheet1$A1:C20]
WHERE  ID = [Sheet1$E2]
```

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office2010developertrainingcourse_vbalab_topic3.aspx
- http://sathyabh.at/2010/10/12/creating-and-editing-parameterized-queries-in-excel-2007/
- [how to pass parameters to query in SQL (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434768/how-to-pass-parameters-to-query-in-sql)