Excel OLEDB connection to SQL Server - Command isnt supported
I need:

excel to be able to change commandtext of existing OLEDB Connection via VBA with indication of @user_id, i.e. exec prcDb_TMReport 127

I have :

stored procedure on SQL server (exec prcDb_TMReport @user_id)
service login & password for database with rights to run procedures
excel file with connection to my SQL Server
VBA code to change commandtext

ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = "exec prcDb_TMReport 127"
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").Refresh

Im fine to set up my initial (first) connection with commandtext i.e.
exec prcDb_TMReport 128

I get connected, my table gets refreshed. But if I want to change commandtext I experience following issues:

On refresh im getting 1004 error
My properties option when right-clicking on query gets greyed out
Right-clicking on query & selecting refresh does nothing
Right-clicking on table & selecting refresh throws error The command 'exec prcDb_TMReport 127' isnt supported


It looks like you want to pass a parameter to your stored procedure. Take a look at this solution. I think it is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434768/how-to-pass-parameters-to-query-in-sql-excel
